# Google App Engine - How to get a list of all app administrators?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I want to programmatically retrieve a list of all the app administrators from within the app. However, I've found no APIs in User Service section that can accomplish this. Is there any way or any undocumented API to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not an API to programatically get a list of administrators for your app.  However, you could create an augmented user model which includes extra information like this.

I'm not sure why you need a list of all admins, but if you just wanted to e-mail them then you could use the [`send_mail_to_admins()`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/functions.html) function.

Comment: Yes,you got it.I am using send_mail_to_admins(),but I want to log who I sent email to in my app.The best way is to use a model to record all adminstrators as far as I could see.